# Unity Android App Bundle Builds sometimes have double size

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

We are using Google's App Delivery package in our game to escape APK download size limit. First a few builds were completely fine. But later, our download sizes on the play store became double size (505 MB) than before (267 MB). I converted AAB file to APKS using bundletool and I saw it contains copy of every APK.

[See the app bundle content here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuxvO.png)

[Also my app bundle settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acvE5.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did the download size change when the app was in the production track or an internal track?

Answer (score 0):

Unity builds for the two Universal CPU-architectures (ARM64 and ARMv7). If needed you might switch to specific architecture in Player Settings -> Other settings -> Target Architectures.
Keep in mind, that the users download size won´t increase by your double sized upload. The devices identify the correct build by their architecture.

Comment: I know how it is working. The download size is doubled on the store side. It is downloading 505 MB, but some builds are 267 - 268 mb as should be.